# Python MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - Only want to update some of the columns

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to update records in MySQL with Python (if an update exists, of course). So far, my initial query looks like this and works fine:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT into orders (`record_id`, `order_id`, `asin`, `item_price`, `promotion_discount`, `quantity`, `promotion_id`, `purchase_date`, `status`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (recordID, orderID, asin, itemPrice, promotionDiscount, qty, promotionId, purchaseDate, status))
```

Now, my dilemma is if I want to update just the itemPrice and status - do I have to update all fields - code below has an error of:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

And here is the query for that:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT into orders (`record_id`, `order_id`, `asin`, `item_price`, `promotion_discount`, `quantity`, `promotion_id`, `purchase_date`, `status`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (`record_id`, `order_id`, `asin`, `item_price`, `promotion_discount`, `quantity`, `promotion_id`, `purchase_date`, `status`) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (recordID, orderID, asin, itemPrice, promotionDiscount, qty, promotionId, purchaseDate, status))
```

recordID is a unique key

Really, I just need to update a couple of the fields, but I'm not sure how to do it since the placeholders are already defined. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My first code example that works correctly is just for inserting data - there isn't an update statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this will do is attempt to insert and if it fails because of the duplicate key error it will provide the values into the updated format:

```
try:
    your query

except mysql.connector.IntegrityError:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE orders set item_price = {0}, status = '{1}' where record_id = {3}".format(itemPrice, status, record_id))
```

Comment: I appreciate the thought - not completely sure I could get this to work as the condition would be based on a value in the database. For example, an item might be in the database with a 'pending' status - and when my script runs again it might have a 'shipped' status - so, when the script runs again, it just needs to update status on that item if it finds a duplicate key. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Yea, for some reason I'm not able to get the new string formatting thing working .format(), etc... and I did try/except vs try/catch

Comment: No problem. Which columns are strings? and just place single ticks around them + except yup!